# Script para cambiar plan de energía en un portatil no funciona

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, .bat

Soy nuevo en batch y estoy haciendo un script en batch para cambiar el plan de energía, para elegir entre el plan predeterminado que viene predefinido por el sistema y otro plan de energía que he personalizado para mejorar el rendimiento cuando quiero jugar.

Antes tenia 2 script separados que cambiaban el plan de energía, uno para cada plan, pero ahora quiero unificarlo todo en uno y como podeis ver, he hecho un condicional para elgir entre los dos planes de energía, el problema es que ahora que los comandos estan dentro de los condicionales me dan problemas al ejecutarse.

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
Parámetros no válidos. Pruebe "/?" para obtener ayuda
```

El problema no es de los comandos ya que cuando los ejecuto directamente desde el cmd o desde los script por separados si que funcionan, el problema es al meterlos dentro de las opciones del condicional.

Dejo por aquí el código:

```
@echo off

:inicio
SET var=0
cls
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo  1    Modo equilibrado  
echo  2    Modo gaming
echo.

SET /p var= ^> Seleccione una opcion [1-2]:

if "%var%"=="1" goto op1
if "%var%"=="2" goto op2

::Mensaje de error, validación cuando se selecciona una opción fuera de rango
echo. El numero "%var%" no es una opcion valida, por favor intente de nuevo.
echo.
pause
echo.
goto:inicio

:op1
    echo.
    echo. Cambiando plan de energia a modo equlibrado
    echo.
    powercfg -SETACTIVE 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
    echo.
    echo. Plan de energia cambiado a modo equilibrado
    goto:salir

:op2
    echo.
    echo. Cambiando plan de energia a modo gaming
    echo.
    powercfg -SETACTIVE 6f6c12a8-f34d-4d4a ba70-5af731d6177b
    echo.
    echo. Plan de energia cambiado a modo gaming
    goto:salir

:salir
    echo.
    echo. Saliendo del programa
    pause
```

Comment: Ya probaste el comando `powercfg -SETACTIVE 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e` directamente en consola para ver que funcione? Porque asumo que es en esa línea la que te da error ya que repliqué el bat sin ejecutar dichos comandos y no me da problema.

Comment: Si, cuando ejecuto esa liena en la consola no me da ningun error, el problema es cuando la ejecuto en el bat

Comment: Cuando salga de la oficina veré si lo pruebo en mi laptop. Puedes enviarme un link donde vea que ese comando es seguro?? porque no voy a probar nada sin estar seguro de donde viene ese comando.

Comment: Ya he soluciando el problema, tenías razon, el GUID del plan de energuía cambia si se realiza algun cambio dentro de este plan, por lo tanto al hacer referencia a este GUID  inexistente estaba dando error. He estado buscando pero no encuentro informacion sobre si estos GUID son constantes o cambian al reinicar el ordenador, por lo tanto no se como de util será este script. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Técnicamente hablando no servirá de nada, viene siendo igual a mi archivo para optimizar Wind2, que "mata" procesos innecesarios, pero no puedo hacer nada con los procesos que se crean cada día y que terminan con nombres aleatorios del tipo **process_name_45sd45e**, aun no he encontrado la forma de matarlos... Pero todos los procesos con nombres fijos los mato cada 1 hora...

Comment: Hay un comando que es `powercfg -LIST` que lista todos planes de energuía con sus GUID pero no se si existe alguna forma de importar los GUID desde esa lista a el programa para que funcione aunque cambien los GUID. Si sabes algo de ese estilo dimelo, te dejo por aqui un enlace para que compruebes que estos comandos son seguros: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options

Comment: Pero de nada te servirá si el comando sigue siendo `powercfg -SETACTIVE` porque no tienes una referencia exacta, osea hoy puede ser **powercfg -SETACTIVE XXX** y mañana puede ser un hash diferente como **powercfg -SETACTIVE XXYZ**. Creo que eso es lo que te entendí cuando dijiste que al parecer los GUID cambian al reiniciar el ordenador.

Comment: No estoy seguro de si cambian, no he encontrado informacion sobre ello, pero lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna forma de copiar lo que devuelve el comando `powercfg -LIST`, solo la parte guid, pero hacerlo todo dentro del bat, de esta forma si cambia el GUID puedes seguir cambiando la configuración.